# Malloc/free own implementation

Tags: c, malloc, free

I'm currently trying to write my own implementation of `malloc`, and `free`.

During my research I've found some implementation which request free `memoryspace` with:

```
block = sbrk(totalSize);
```

then there is some other code

and finally they `return`:

```
return (block + 1);
```

But i don't understand why the `+ 1` is necessary.

Another thing i don't understand why some implementation have a `magic number` in their `struct`.

I already searched the web and stackoverflow but didn't find any answers to my question.

Comment: _Why do they have a magic number_ ? Hard to tell without seeing the actual source code. _Why is there a `+1`_? Also hard to tell without seeing the actual source code.

Comment: For example: https://github.com/danluu/malloc-tutorial/blob/master/malloc.c

Comment: Also, have you heard of `mmap`?

Comment: yeah i have heard of `mmap`. Why?

Comment: 'Cause using `mmap()` for backing `malloc()` storage is much more flexible...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you returned memory from your allocator. All's fine, the user does something with it, and gives your `free` a pointer. That's it, all you get is an address.

How are you supposed to know from an address alone:

1. That it was allocated by you to begin with?
2. That you haven't freed it already?
3. How big is the memory block it points at?

You must store some meta-data *somewhere*. The approach illustrated by the examples you described, is to store the meta-data right before the raw memory you give to the caller of `malloc`. That way, to retrieve it all you have to do is  a simple bit of pointer arithmetic with the address you were handed in `free`.

After that, what meta-data to store is up to you. A magic number is one way to document that the following block was allocated by you. If its bit pattern is sufficiently "distinct" then you'll rarely try to free a block you haven't allocated yourself.

Comment: Moreover, in the example the OP linked in comments and seems to have relied upon, the pointer `block`, to which the pointer returned by `sbrk()` is assigned, is of the suggestively-named type `struct block_meta *`.  Adding one of course results in a pointer to just past one such structure.

Answer (score 2):

Story Teller has most of the .... story! Pun intended.

Two other points. First an often missed requirement of `malloc()` is to return aligned memory. `malloc()` isn't told what it's allocating and so is required to return a block with "the maximum alignment".
If your platform has even alignment (2 byte alignment) where things like `int` can't start on odd addresses (or just aren't efficient) then `+1` might be rounding up. Though it doesn't make much sense to ever return an odd-length block in those circumstances.

Secondly, another smart debug feature is to put some familiar pattern at the end of blocks to check for buffer end overwrites (e.g. out by 1 errors).

I personally think `0xDEADC0D3` is a good block of 4 bytes but that's my sense of humour.